# Triggering a script when filesystem usage changes considerably

Tags: swap, tmpfs

Is there an existing solution for `systemd` based systems to call a user defined script when usage on some filesystem exceeds or falls short of certain limits, without implementing a polling every some seconds which sounds inefficient ?

For some device mapper based devices, `dmeventd` can trigger a script based on snapshot usage levels, but this works on the block device level. I'm seeking a solution on the filesystem level.

The first thing I would like to use it for is to adjust `tmpfs` limits dynamically based on current swap space usage: If some program wants to use more `/tmp` space, enough swap is still free and the amount of dirty pages is low enough, the script can increase the limit in `mount -oremount,size=%LIMIT /tmp` and reduce it to a minimum after files are deleted.
But if swap is almost full or too many dirty pages (the program in question writing too fast), the script would instead log the current usage, find the causing process using `lsof` and keep the tmp limit low to ensure system stability.

I'm unsure about the right tags to use so suggestions are welcome.